# Custom Post Type Not Accepting Page Variable

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom post type using PODS
The URL ends up being:

http://example.com/dj/dj-name

The dj has an author field that I am using to query the DJ's posts.

The url for next_posts_link(); ends up becoming /dj/dj-name/page/2 as one would expect.

After clicking the link wordpress seems to be ignoring the /page/2 and just redirecting back to /dj/dj-name

My permalink structure is: http://example.com/sample-post/

When I use default permalink structure /?dj=dj-name&paged=2 it works correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the value of `$paged`?

Comment: @celeriko it never gets to that point because wordpress redirects back to /dj/dj-name

Comment: it does get to that point, or else the query would not be executed and there would be nothing displayed on the page.

Comment: @celeriko It get's to that point if I am on /dj/dj-name...  However when I go to /dj/dj-name/page/2 it is NOT that it is displaying data from /dj/dj-name it is PHYSICALLY redirecting me to the url /dj/dj-name... Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP file, do you assign `$paged` to anything? [View Pagination Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Adding_the_.22paged.22_parameter_to_a_query)

Above your query, probably right below your `get_header()` you need to add something like this:

`$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;`

If that doesn't work you can try saving your Permalinks again (Settings -> Permalinks -> Save Permalinks). This will refresh your current permalink structure.

Finally, if you have a page called "dj-name" already created, you can run into problems because WordPress can't differentiate between a subpage called `page/2/` and a pagination link `page/2/`

Comment: Yes I do have that up at the top. Again the issue is wordpress is sending me back to /dj/dj-name as if /dj/dj-name/page/2 is an invalid URL

Comment: Maybe if you move the `<?php next_posts_link(); ?>` before the `endif;`

Comment: <?php next_posts_link(); ?> is generating the proper link. Upon clicking it when I view source. Upon clicking it, wordpress **redirects** me back to /dj/dj-name.

Comment: Did you try moving it before the endif? It may be generating the correct link, but not the corresponding query since it is a custom one.

Comment: Yes, still the same result. Even if I type the proper in the URL bar. It redirects back.

Comment: On a side note, you really should use WP_Query instead of [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) since WP_Query is faster and you have more control. Are you 100% sure there's more than 1 page? Maybe if you pass max num pages into your next_posts_link() -> `<?php next_posts_link( 'Next Post', $query->max_num_pages ); ?>`

Comment: Turns out you can't use WP_Query at all with what I was trying to do. Fix is below.

Answer (score 0):

Pagination only works on archive pages such as index.php, category.php, archive-posttype.php etc.

You can make it work on single.php or similar pages but you need to hijack the built in redirect function, see below...

```
function dj_redirect_hack($url) {
    if ( is_single() and get_post_type() == 'dj' ) $url = false;
    return $url;
}
add_filter('redirect_canonical','dj_redirect_hack');
```